# tailwindcss, the output CSS file and the @apply CSS rule

Tags: responsive-design, tailwind-css, hidden

I have 3 blocks of text in which i will apply properties for mobile devices.
Below i have 3 other blocks in which i will apply other properties for larger screen.
I made a div (div class="mobiles_only")  containing these 3 blocks and try to create a class with css syntax in output file :

```
.mobiles_only{ 
@apply sm:hidden; /* these blocks must be removed for larger screens */
}
```

And a div (div class="larger_screens_only") for the 3 blocks below :

```
.larger_screens_only{
apply hidden;  /* these blocks must be removed for mobile screens */
}
```

When tailwindcss rebuilds, my classes are not saved  !
Also i do not know how watch can be started when i open this project on which i try to use tailwind :-(

VSCode Version : 1.79.2
Node.js : 16.17.1
V8 : 10.8.168.25-electron.0
Système d’exploitation : Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Comment: I just found this :  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values   will try to add some properties using that way...